# Are bug reports suitable for this site?

Tags: discussion, scope

Recently there was a bug report posted as a question here. I was hoping the community could discuss whether this should be done or not.

Comment: Of course bug reports are not suitable, but how do users you know it's a bug? What if they do not recognize it as bug and post it as regular question?

Answer (score 25):

Questions that are simply problem reports are **not suitable** for Ubuntu Stack Exchange.

[Launchpad](http://launchpad.net) is the place to report bugs, its where developers are monitoring for such things, and is more suited to the problem.

If it's not *very obviously* a bug, though, I think we can leave it. If it's behavior which might be a bug or, say, a case of [PEBKAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error), err on the side of being more permissive.

Comment: Any ideas on how to improve this? I've seen more and more questions which should be bug reports, perhaps mention it in the faq? Is there a way we can maybe add a disclaimer thing in the comment form telling people where to report bugs?

Comment: A gentle reminder pointing people to launchpad would suffice.

Comment: I regularly do this - e.g. [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5708/unity-does-not-display-properly/9063) (which was later closed in this case)

Comment: It's very clear that bug reports don't belong here. It's also clear that users don''t usually know if they have been affected by a bug.  I think it's appropriate to point them toward the bug report and instruct them to click the "affects me too" so that developers can get a better understanding of the impact the bug is having. I do this despite the fact that I fully expect the question to be closed.

Answer (score 11):

I believe that Bugs are OK.

The person asking the question might not know if their problem is a bug or a problem with their setup.

The person may realize its a bug but be looking for a work around.

If someone asks a question which turns out to be a bug the correct answer is:

> This is a known bug (link to bug report) you might want to try this work around (description of possible work around)

I do not believe just closing a question is helpful, it sends the wrong message to people trying out Ubuntu.

I also believe that if people run into a problems with ubuntu they should be able to find answers and solutions on this site. Just closing someones question will not do that.

Comment: Agreed, because most people do not know that it is a bug. So they should have at least that info from this site.

Answer (score 3):

I'm gonna say no, because bug reports are something the program's author should be looking into, and not the community at large.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, newcomers feel a tad bewildered by this site and yesterday I came across some obsolete information on the Ask site that stated there was a fix to a certain issue I had which only turned out to be a bug. In reality this issue was answered incorrectly and since hasn't been taken down. When I viewed the FAQ's I saw a reference (not sure where it is now) regarding listing bug reports in Meta.  I did that and my question & answer was migrated as a post to Ask Ubuntu instead of the individual explaining that the information should have been reported using Launchpad.  In reality I don't think this site is very kind or user friendly to new comers in general.  Also because it is points driven valid issues are being marked down or ignored instead of explaining the proper way to present them.  These are my thoughts.  Now I will go and post that bug report by yet another means as I am attempting to alert someone that data related to a fix regarding this issue is incorrect and save them hours of time with respect to research. *Grammatical change.

Comment: Meta is for discussing about this website, Not for posting bug reports.

Comment: This is fine be that as it may if it were not for misinformation the report would have been submitted via Launchpad.

Comment: ^please explain it, Did'nt got your point

Comment: I apologize if there is a communications issue; however, my point is clear when I read the text posted by myself above.  There was incorrect information posted on Ask Ubuntu.  For me this is about accurate information regarding a fix for an issue.  I shouldn't come across information which slates itself as a fix and yet is is actually a bug to get technical so that I am emphatically clear. This not someone just answering a question for points.  It is about someone answering a question with correct information thus earning points.  Have a wonderful day:-)

Comment: I did'nt tested that workaround so I don't whether it work or not, If you belive that it is a bug, You can post an an as ' this is a known bug' with link to bugreport, :)

Comment: Well I can only go by my own experience and although I am a Ubuntu Novice I'm not computer illiterate nor am I a new comer to desktop computing. I am not just clear on issues of this particular platform and how it's done. However, to circumvent this issue and as I've stated before I will reiterate I'm a good study and a quick learner.  Thanks again I'll be sure to keep the posting mechanism which you just referenced above in mind.

Comment: Where's the link to the question? Let's just not talk vaguely, if something is wrong let's just fix it!

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the top 2 answers above ([this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/228/47343) and [this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/605/47343));

I think it might also be a good idea to consider offering a **recommendation on whether uncertain cases (possible bug) should be asked as a question here at AskUbuntu or at Ubuntu Launchpad**.