# Make [architecture] a synonym of [cpu-architecture]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I propose to make [architecture](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/architecture) a synonym of [cpu-architecture](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cpu-architecture) and retag all questions.

Although [architecture](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/architecture) is the bigger tag, it is not as unambiguous as [cpu-architecture](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cpu-architecture) which I would favour as master tag for that reason. The tag excerpts and wikis should be copied then of course.

Some stats about the two tags:

---

**[cpu-architecture](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cpu-architecture)**

- 18 questions
- 1 followers
- Excerpt:

  > Running or compiling binaries made for CPU architectures different than the host system
- Wiki: *none*

---

**[architecture](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/architecture)**

- 86 questions
- 0 followers
- Excerpt:

  > Architectures usually refer to the difference between 32-bit x86 (i386) and 64-bit x86-64 (amd64/em64t) processors. Both are distinct architectures.
- Wiki:

  > Architectures usually refer to the difference between [32-bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/32-bit) x86 (i386) and [64-bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/64-bit) x86-64 (amd64/em64t) processors. Both are distinct [architectures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_architecture). Use a tag specific to one architecture when a problem is believed to be architecture-specific.
  >
  > For example, if you're having a problem just with the amd64 live CD, and the i386 live CD worked fine, tag your question [64-bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/64-bit). Note that some architecture-specific problems are bugs (and Ask Ubuntu is [not the place](https://askubuntu.com/faq#questions) to [report bugs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug), as [detailed here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/226/are-bug-reports-suitable-for-this-site)).
  >
  > Ubuntu supports the following architectures:
  >
  > - amd64 (x64)
  > - i386 (x86)
  > - [ARM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM)
  > - PPC/PowerPC (Old macs) -- This is unofficial.
  >
  > A processor that can run the amd64 architecture can run the i386 architecture also, as the processor is backward-compatible to a 16-bit architecture. Generally, most OSes start in 16-bit mode, then, very early, switch the CPU to i386, and optionally, amd64 mode.
  >
  > For questions about running 32-bit Ubuntu software on 64-bit Ubuntu systems, use the [multarch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/multarch) tag.
  >
  > The [architecture](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/architecture) tag should not be used in the sense of [design principles and decisions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_architecture) (unless, of course, they are *also* about computer architecture as described above). For such questions, please use the [design](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/design) tag instead.

Comment: Here is a merge needed too.